# Ordering a list of mixed data types in lisp

Tags: lisp, symbols, clisp

Given a list of any length and data type calculate:

- Lower item
- Higher item
- Symbols
- Average
- Reversed list (implementing the function)

I've been trying to learn lisp by myself, since my class is kinda useless (read my other question =_=;), and I've done this:

```
(defun higher(l)
    (let (x)
        (setf x (first (sort l #'>)))))
```

Then it didn't order symbols, of course... so I tried this:

```
(defun higher(l)
    (let ((x 0))
        (dolist (a l)
            (setf a (coerce a 'integer))
            (if (> a x)
                (setf x a)))
        x))
```

but coerce is not helping me to make my symbols integers... thanks in advance for your help, and also, I would like to know if I'm formatting well (I wasn't taught to use "let").

Comment: Start by writing a function that can compare two values of any type.

Comment: Your teacher may appreciate if you show you know how to use *recursion*.

Comment: Also see what you can do with e.g. [`REDUCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm).

Comment: But what do you use to compare to values of any type? I can't seem to find good documentation of lisp anywhere (just tutorials and that kind of stuff...)

Comment: You already use #'< to compare numbers. There are similar functions #'string< and #'char< that likely do what you want. As you are supposed to be able to compare *any data type* you need to decide and implement what it means in general for one item to be less than another.

Comment: I found the documentation, sorry for that... #'char< appears to not work with symbols, I tried to do (sort '(b a d c) #'char>) with result "argument A is not a character"

Comment: Now you have to decide what it means for one symbols to be less than another. Such as that the `STRING` of the symbol is less in alphabetical order.

Comment: Although using `SORT` will work, you should consider a more elegant implementation if you'd like to get any respect from your teacher and others.

Comment: By the way, in your first example, there is no need to use "let".  You may be doing this because that would be natural in some other languages.  But the body of a function is an expression, so the let and setf are superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function #'Char> won't work with symbols, because symbol is not type character.

Before you compare symbols you can use [symbol-name](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_2.htm):

```
(symbol-name 'a)
CL-USER> "A"
```

So now you can use #'string>

To write function which compare> any data type you can use [typecase](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_tpcase.htm#typecase).
Small example:

```
(defun compare> (x y)
  (when (subtypep (type-of x) (type-of y))
    (typecase (and x y)
      (integer (> x y))
      (character (char> x y)))))
```

As Terje said, you shouldn't use sort, [reduce](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm) is much more better :)